# Cosine Modulo $p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials, finite-fields

Consider the integers modulo a prime $p$. I'm looking for a nice polynomial function that acts as a sort of "cosine" on the integers modulo $p$. Specifically, I'm looking for solutions to the double angle formula:

$$2*q(t)^2 - 1 = q(2t)$$

where $q(t)$ is a polynomial on the integers modulo $p$ or another ``easily computable'' function in $t$.

I have a class of examples that already satisfy the relation. Let $x^2+y^2 =1$ modulo $p$. Then define $q(t)$ to be the real part of $(x+iy)^t$ (in $\mathbb{Z}_p[i]$) (which can be written as some complicated polynomial modulo $p$). One can check that $q(t)$ indeed satisfies the double angle recurrence.

But these examples are kind of complicated (they require computations in an extension field) as well as the explicit formula for the coefficients of $q(t)$ in this case is difficult to write down.

Can anyone come up with another class of examples or something that is either more natural or more easily computable? Can anyone come up with an example that doesn't use an extension field to be constructed?

I would like the image to be all the integers modulo $p$. See the second example below.

Edit (2nd example):
A second class of examples is $\cos(t) = 1/2 * \left(a^t +a^{-t}\right)$ for some generator $a$ of $GF(p)$ or $GF(p^2)$. However, if $x^2-1$ is not a quadratic residue then there is no solution to $\cos(t) = x$ unless $a$ is in an extension field. So in this case, to get a full image we still need to work over an extension field.

Comment: Doesn't $q(t)\equiv 1$ work over any finite field?

Comment: Three quick comments.(1)  It's probably better to write $\mathbb F_p$ for the finite field, and reserve $\mathbb Z_p$ for the ring of $p$-adic integers. (2) If $p\equiv1\pmod4$, then $\mathbb F_p$ already contains a square root of $-1$, so you can probably use your formula coming from $x+yi$ in the ring $\mathbb F_p[x,y]$ without going to the extension field $\mathbb F_{p^2}$. (3) The polynomial $f_n(Z)=2Z^2-1$ you want $Z=q(t)$ to give $q(2t)$ is the 2nd Chebychev polynomial. Are you looking for some $q_n(t)$ so that $f_n(q_n(t))=q_n(nt)$, where $f_n$ is the $n$th Chebychev polynomial?

Comment: Do you want $2q(t)^2-1=q(2t)$ as polynomials, or do you want the equality to hold for any $t\in\mathbb F_p$? It seems that they cannot be equal as polynomials when $q$ is non-constant, since the degrees do not match.

Comment: @JoeSilverman (2) I see, thank you. (3), exactly, if I can get the $n=2$ case I should be able to generalize easily.

Comment: To correct the problem that @KentaSuzuki is pointing out, you could try using formal power series; however, if you do, you run into hard problems with the coefficients. For example, if $p = 3$, you can start with $q_0 = 1$, and find that $q_1 = 0$. Then $q_2$ can be anything (as we should expect), $q_3 = 0$. But when trying to find $q_4$, you run into $16 q_4 = 2 q_2^2 + 4 q_4$, which can only be solved in $\mathbb{F}_3$ if $q_2 = 0$. Which you should expect, since the coefficients of $\cos$ as a formal power series have denominators with increasing powers of $p$.

Comment: Also, $q(t) \equiv -\frac{1}{2}$ satisfies the condition much like $q(t) \equiv 1$.

Comment: @KentaSuzuki I just want equality as values mod $p$, not polynomials.

Comment: Every map of sets from a finite field to itself is a polynomial, so asking that $q$ be a polynomial is no restriction at all.

Comment: In the spirit of the question: when $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, there are no nontrivial functions $\cos, \sin: \mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p$ satisfying the usual trig formulas for $\cos(x+y)$ and $\sin(x+y)$. For if there were, we could pick a square root $i \in \mathbb{F}_p$ of $-1$, and the function $x\mapsto\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ would then be a monoid homomorphism $e:(\mathbb{F}_p,+,0)\to(\mathbb{F}_p,\cdot,1)$. But there is no nontrivial such homm. For if $\ker(e)$  is trivial then $\mathrm{im}(e)$ is a $p$-element subgroup of the codomain (impossible); so $e$ is trivial. (Continues)

Comment: Hence $\cos(x) + i\sin(x) = 1$ for all $x$. Rearrange as $i\sin(x) = 1 - \cos(x)$, square both sides, then use $\cos^2 + \sin^2 = 1$ to get $\cos(x) = 1$ for all $x$. Then $\sin(x) = 0$ for all $x$. Conclusion: the only trig functions $\cos, \sin: \mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p$ that really behave like their real analogues are trivial, at least when $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.